# Downloading files and opening them

Tags: c#, file, windows-8, download, windows-8.1

I have a user control that should display a video file.

The code is:

```
//The code does: Checks if file exists, if yes - opens, if not - goes to download manager and downloads it. 
//After await dMan.downloadVideo(link); finishes - function recursivly calls itself, but code runs into Unauthorized Access Exception
private async void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await LoadVideo();
    }

    private async Task LoadVideo()
    {
        string link = "http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/MPEG-4/MargotGagnon.mov";
        DownloadManager dMan = new DownloadManager();
        bool FileNeedsDownload = false;
        try
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Margot.mp4");
            var stream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            VideoPlayer.SetSource(stream, sampleFile.FileType);
        }
        catch
        {
            FileNeedsDownload = true;
        }
        if (FileNeedsDownload == true)
        {
            await dMan.downloadVideo(link);
            LoadVideo();
        }
    }
```

My downloading code:

```
public async Task downloadVideo(string link)
    {
        string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path.ToString();
            string urlLink = link;
            await getVideoByUrl(urlLink, "Margot.mp4");
    }
    async public Task getVideoByUrl(string url, string filename)
    {
        HttpClientHandler aHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        aHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
        HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient(aHandler);
        aClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await aClient.GetAsync(url);
        byte[] img = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();// ReadAsByteArray();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        // To save downloaded image to local storage
        var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0));

        writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
        await writer.StoreAsync();
        //current.image.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
        writer.DetachStream();
        await fs.FlushAsync();

        // To save downloaded image to bitmap
        //DataWriter writer2 = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
        //writer2.WriteBytes(img);
        //await writer2.StoreAsync();
        //current.image = new BitmapImage();
        //current.image.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
    }
```

Exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException was caught
>     HResult=-2147024891
>     Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>          at SalesPlays.Controls.VideoControl.d__3.MoveNext() in c:\Users\afomenko\Desktop***\Controls\VideoControl.xaml.cs:line 43
>     InnerException:

**P.S. When i run app after a crush - video is downloaded ( offcourse, because the downloading works ) and opens the video. Why it fails with unthorized in the first time?**

Maybe some stream isn't closed in my downloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was in my saving code!

Here is a working sample:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
    var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outStream);
    dataWriter.WriteString("Hello from Test!");
    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
    dataWriter.DetachStream();
    await outStream.FlushAsync();
    outStream.Dispose(); // 
    fs.Dispose();
}
```